# How to replace a string that contains "c:\test.zip" with @"c:\test.zip"

Tags: c#, directory

My problem is :

I need to write an application that zips one file.

The application successfully reads the file from an user defined location, but the trouble is, I can't make it to write the archive file name to a specified folder without getting an annoying error : `"The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\bg\Desktop\1323.zip`' because it is being used by another process." at the line : 
archiver.OpenArchive (`System.IO.FileMode.Create`);

Here is my c sharp code :

```
private void zipThatFileToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream myStream;
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "zip files (*.zip)|*.zip|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
        saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if ((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                ZipForge archiver = new ZipForge();

                // The name of the ZIP file to be create
                string env = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
                //MessageBox.Show(env);

                //this doesn't work
                archiver.FileName = env;

                //this works
                //archiver.FileName = @"D:\test.zip";

                // Specify FileMode.Create to create a new ZIP file
                // or FileMode.Open to open an existing archive


                archiver.OpenArchive (System.IO.FileMode.Create);
                // Default path for all operations             
                archiver.BaseDir = @"C:\Users\bg\Desktop\";
                // Add file C:\file.txt the archive; wildcards can be used as well
                archiver.AddFiles(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                // Close archive
                archiver.CloseArchive();
                MessageBox.Show("The archive was created! ");
                myStream.Close();
            }
        }
```

I'm using this http://www.componentace.com/zip-file-in-c-sharp.htm with this http://www.componentace.com/zip-file-in-c-sharp.htm

Comment: Yes, just remove second if clause, you've already checked DialogResult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say for sure, but it looks as if you're trying to open the same file twice -- first when you call `"myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null"`

, and again when you call `"archiver.OpenArchive (System.IO.FileMode.Create);"`

I'd suggest perhaps closing myStream before you start your archive operations.

Answer (score 1):

Considering it appears as you're opening the file twice, why dont you just call **myStream.Close()** before you open it the second time?

Answer (score 1):

I never used `ZipForge` before but I can say that, your problem probably occuring because of your file access options. Look at `File.Open()` method;

```
public static FileStream Open(
    string path,
    FileMode mode,
    FileAccess access,
    FileShare share
)
```

> Defines constants for read, write, or read/write access to a file.